# Query con tablas de servidores diferentes

Tags: sql-server

Necesito hacer una consulta a tablas de dos bases de datos diferentes y en servidores diferentes pero tienen un campo en comun, use la siguiente sintaxis pero me manda ese error

***Query:***

```
use BD_ALMACEN
go

select F.Codigo, ...
from Fac F

left join [MA-P111].BDFACTURAS..TablaDatos P
on F.Codigo=P.Codigo
```

***Error:***

> No se encuentra el servidor 'MA-P111' en sys.servers. Compruebe que se
>   haya especificado  el nombre de servidor correcto. Si es necesario,
>   ejecute el procedimiento almacenado  sp_addlinkedserver para agregar
>   el servidor a sys.servers.

Comment: ¿Existe el `linked server` MA-P111 en el servidor?

Comment: que es linked server? disculpe @PatricioMoracho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estimado,

El error te indica que no tienes asociado un servidor vinculado, por lo cual no puedes enlazar esta consulta.

Básicamente un servidor vinculado nos permite conectarnos a otros servidores dentro de nuestra instancia SQL Server.
Con el siguiente Store Procedure puedes agregar un servidor vinculado a tu instancia, tienes mayor detalle de como crear un Servidor vinculado en la documentación de MSFT [Create Linked Servers (SQL Server Database Engine)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017).

```
USE [master]  
GO  
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver   
    @server = N'SERVERNAME',   
    @srvproduct=N'SQL Server' ;  
GO
```

En el siguiente [enlace](https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-crear-y-configurar-un-servidor-enlazado-en-sql-server-management-studio/), trata de como agregar servidores vinculados de forma gráfica.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, te sugiero modificar esta publicación en base a [answer] , recuerda : " No todos pueden acceder a sitios externos, y los enlaces se pueden quebrar con el tiempo.", saludos.

Comment: @Jorgesys muchas gracias por tu acotación, a veces por responder de forma oportuna se nos van detalles que nos permitirían contribuir de mejor forma. Edite la respuesta y espero se ejemplifique de mejor manera ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias Esteban,  se agradece mucho tu contribución, la cual es excelente, gracias por modificar tu respuesta! @Esteban , saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Además de lo indicado, deberás especificar el nombre de objeto en “4 partes” sustituyendo  [MA-P111].BDFACTURAS..TablaDatos por [MA-P111].BDFACTURAS.dbo.TablaDatos o el esquema correspondiente.

Comment: Exacto, el orden es: [Servidor].[Base de Datos].[esquema].[Objeto]